# How can I start a google chrome instance which uses a proxy while already having chrome running

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, session, socks-proxy

On linux, one can use this

```
google-chrome-stable --proxy-server="socks://localhost:4444"
```

to start google chrome and tell it to use a local SOCKS server.

However this only works when chrome is not already running, otherwise it politely says

```
Opening in existing browser session.
```

and the proxy setting has no effect.

How can I use both a session with proxy and one without, at the same time? I don't want to use different "profiles" or "incognito".

Answer (score 4):

The only solution I found is using the `--user-data-dir` switch. It will open another session with the proxy specified

Comment: Worked well for me on Windows, I don't care if I pass a temporary data dir to it since I'm using the `--guest` flag anyways.